# Using Perl RegExp in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string from which I'm trying to extract the term preceeding a keyword.

```
str = "This is a <Keyword>(-)Controlled design"
```

There can be a space between keyword and controlled or a "-". I need to extract the  before "Controlled". In Perl, I'm using the below regular expression:

```
/(\w+)[- ]controlled/i)
```

I am trying the same in R after handling the backslashes and setting `perl=TRUE`. But it doesn't work. How can I use this expression to extract the  in R? Is there a an alternate expression/library that I can use?

Thanks in advance,
simak

Comment: You do realize that the argument name is `perl`, right?

Comment: yes yes. I did give "perl=true" in lowercase. Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that it's `TRUE`, not `true`? :)

Comment: Yes Roman, I do realize that its perl and not PERL and TRUE but not true. I put in the correct case in the expression - just not here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `str_match` from [stringr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html).

```
> library(stringr)
> str <- "This is a keyword-Controlled design"
> str_match(str, "(?i)(\\w+)[- ]controlled")[2]
[1] "keyword"
```

Comment: Thanks - this will work too. However, Within str_match, is a group match not allowed using the "|" symbol?  For example, if I were to extract the keyword before controlled or controls, I tried the below: But didnt get anything. Is this not allowed?  str_match(str, "(?i)(\\w+)[- ]controlled|controls")[2]

Comment: You should group the suffixes: str_match(str, "(?i)(\\w+)[- ](controlled|controls)")[2]

Answer (score 5):

Would something like this be good enough using `gsub`?

```
str <- "This is a keyword-Controlled design"

gsub("(.+\\s)?(\\w+)(\\s|-)(Controlled).+","\\2",str)
#[1] "keyword"

gsub("(.+\\s)?(\\w+)(\\s|-)(Controlled).+","\\2",str)
#[1] "keyword"
```

And because regex is not the be all and end all:

```
spl <- unlist(strsplit(str,"[-| ]"))
spl[which(spl=="Controlled")-1]
#[1] "keyword"
```

Comment: Yes- Thanks much!. This will work.I just about got the hang of using RegExps in Perl and now switching to R is completely messing me up. -simak